# Running Soap ui Test Cases

Tags: soapui

I have to run a test case having 5 Test steps. I am running this test case from command prompt. for all the pass scenarios it is working fine. But my problem comes for negative scenarios. let suppose in 3rd Test step, there is a IF condition to check some validation and upon failing of that condition, it want that whole Test Case to get failed and it should not run Step-4 and Step-5 thereafter. 
How can I do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Under TestCase options, you want to turn the Abort on Error option. By default this is off.

Comment: Thats fine, but how explicitly i can put an error statement?

Comment: I don't understand your question.